# android get keyEvent for focusable PopupWindow

Tags: java, android, popup, popupwindow, keyevent

I've got a popup-window like this:

```
View view = li.inflate(R.layout.someview, null);
PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(context);

popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
popup.setWidth(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
popup.setHeight(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
popup.setInputMethodMode(PopupWindow.INPUT_METHOD_NEEDED);

popup.setTouchable(true);
popup.setFocusable(true);
popup.setContentView(view);
```

Inside the popup-window there is an edittext which **definitely needs to be able to get the focus!!**

So I cannot remove the `setFocusable(true);` flag
but I want to receive the keyEvents inside the popup anyway.

So how can I receive key events on an focusable popupwindow?

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use a customised layout which has overriden the dispatch key Event and then send the event to the popupWindow.What i have seen is that the key events are given to the view group in the popupwindow for sure.Please check ViewRootImpl deliverKeyEvent and PopUpWindow's dispatchKeyEvent.